# Powershell to match one row of data from two files and output the row

Tags: powershell

I have two files/outputs.
`$file1` contains:

`Name,Address,Number`

`$file2` contains:

`Name`

I'm looking to match those two files on Name and output the entire line from `$file1`

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Import-Csv .\file1.csv |Join-Object (Import-Csv .\file2.csv) -On Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your files are CSV files:

Combine [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) with [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) to filter those lines, with the help of the 
[`-in`operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin):

```bash
Import-Csv $file1 | # Parse the CSV file into objects
  Where-Object Name -in (Import-Csv $file2).Name # Filter
```

Note:

- This is a conceptually simple, but potentially slow solution, depending on the size of the input files. More efficient - but more elaborate - solutions are possible.
- The filtered CSV rows are output as *objects* (of type `[pscustomobject]`), as parsed by `Import-Csv`; you could convert them back to CSV via [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) (in memory) or save them back to a file with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv).

Comment: Thank you very much! that got my brain juices flowing haha.

In the end, i ended up figuring it out and did this:




`$output = $file2 | Where-Object Name -in $file1`

and then

`$output | Export-csv -path pathtofile`